# How to access a button in a for loop and bind it to on_press in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I run into an error while trying to access two buttons from a group of buttons created in for loop and binding the button to on_press. Please what is the right way to do this (without .kv). How can I access individual button and bind them to different on_press event

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class TestApp(App): 
        def build(self):
               layout=GridLayout(cols=1)
               for i in range(6): 
                    btn = Button(text= str(i)) 
                    layout.add_widget(btn)

# error occurred here      
              btn[0].bind(on_press=first)
              btn[1].bind(on_press=second)

         def first(self):
             pass
         def second(self):
             pass

              return layout

if __name__ == '__main__': 
TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code involving `btn[0]` implies a `btn` list, but there is no such list in your code. Here is a modified version of your code that does what you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout=GridLayout(cols=1)
        for i in range(6):
            btn = Button(text= str(i))
            layout.add_widget(btn)
            if i == 0:
                btn.bind(on_press=self.first)
            elif i == 1:
                btn.bind(on_press=self.second)
        return layout


    def first(self, button_instance):
        print('first')
        
    def second(self, button_instance):
        print('second')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: using the code you gave me when I tried to change the background_color of the first button inside the ' def first()' function   it didn't change

Comment: What does the `first()` function look like?

Comment: The first function looks like this                     def first(self, button_instance):
       #this is not changing the background color 
         self.btn1.background_color=(0,0,1,1)
        print('first')

Comment: The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color) says `To set a plain color, set the background_normal to ''`

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't fully solved my problem, however, the following code returned the object created on the button and the value assigned to it. So I believe that this solution can help you.

```
from functools import partial

for x in test:
    btn = Button(text=x["CustomerName"], background_color=[0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9], size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.mostra,x["CustomerName"]))
    self.ids.grd1.add_widget(btn)

def mostra(self,*args):
    print(args)
```

Looking at the code I posted I used bind after creating the button (`btn.bind`) and in it I passed the function that shows on the screen the value saved in the x of my loop. In the function (`mostra`) the use of `self` and `* args` is mandatory.

At the beginning there is the line (`from functools import partial`) that line is necessary to execute the function show inside the bind.